# Rent insulation blower or continue DIY

Tags: insulation, attic, blower, dust

My current attic is lacking in cellulose insulation. Currently I can see the top of every 2x8 joists by ~ 3/4in. When measured and assumed to be 7in of settled insulation all around, I’m guessing I’m about R21 in the overall attic. Far below the R38-R60 recommendations. When I leave for the morning for work, I turn the upstairs AC from 74 (overnight) to ~78/79. If I don’t the AC Will definitely run all day during the hottest parts of day.

I live zone in VA in Zone 4. So hot muggy summers, and mainly cool/chilly winters, sometimes snow. I have a North facing home to.

I found this article below that explains how to DIY bit by bit of cellulose loose fill. I’ve done a couple bags worth of GreneFiber cellulose and it works fairly well. BUT, it’s very time consuming. I do like that I can do this outside which keeps the dust down. But doing the hailing the can inside, walking along joists, dump, Repeat process is getting old and might not be the most ideal.

https://dengarden.com/home-improvement/How-to-Install-Loose-Fill-Insulation-By-Hand

I’d either like to rent a machine to speed the process up or continue this bit by bit.

What I can’t really decide on is if I should rent a machine and just dump ~18in all around. Or raise the current insulation above the joists, then use unfaced batts to finish off the height requirements.

I know renting a machine can introduce tons of dust, but if the attic is already insulated, wouldn’t this keep the airborne dust to the attic exclusively?

Answer (score 4):

If the machine and the bags can stay outside, the dusty part is confined to the attic.

There is some collateral dust from climbing in and out of the attic. That is usually restricted to a small area.

Placing a large bath or beach towel over the attic access and pulling as much discharge hose as you can in the attic with you helps keep dust down.

Of course wear protective clothing and eye protection as well as a quality mask.   It's sweaty in the summer, and dirty and itchy, but faster than laying out batts.

You really do need 2 people as well. 1 dumping the insulation and 1 spraying. However the risk of misstep and your leg coming through the ceiling is less since you don't have to move around the attic as much as with laying batts. It's easier to get the insulation in tight areas.  I even found is some areas I could "bounce" the spray off the roof sheeting to get it where I want it.

Comment: I imagine you protected/blocked the attic ventilation so it did not get blocked/covered.

Comment: @crip659,  yep, I did...that is one of the areas where the "bounce" method worked.

Answer (score 2):

In general, at least where I shop, cellulose + blower rental is less cost than batt insulation for R-value over area covered. Cellulose also does not have the leaks at joints between batts problem that batts do, and flows around framing with no fuss or cutting required.

I did exactly two bales (testing two brands) by hand and after doing that to prove I could, renting the machine was the obvious choice for doing the whole attic, so I did.

If you're planning to do this in Virginia without waiting for cooler weather, I would suggest getting started *really* early in the morning and stopping when it becomes too hot in the attic. If that means renting the machine a bit longer, well, at least you haven't saved a few bucks in rental just to finish yourself off trying to use it.

Potential for dust in the house depends on how you and the hose are getting into the attic. If you are entering by an outside access, there should be no dust into the house. If you are coming up through a trapdoor or hatch, there will be some, but it's not a huge unsolvable problem, just some additional vacuuming. You may want to block off the area below the attic access to help contain any dust that gets down there, as well as blocking off as much of the hatch as you can from above while working (without making it difficult to leave when you need to.)

Comment: You actually just reminded me that I would need to add insulation up to the baffle and cellulose can get those corners.

Comment: I would likely be going through the front door, up the stairs, into the attic via the drop down stairs. I’d also like to do it sooner rather than later honestly, but I do get where your coming from.

Comment: @Helrazr assume you have no gable vents?

Comment: @Huesmann I have box vents, and individual soffits spaced out ~10+ ft. I want to add additional soffits as there doesn’t appear to be enough IMO. House was built in 1999, so standards weren’t as stringent as todays.

Comment: If you have gable vents that could be removed, that could be an easy entry point for the blower duct.